# Sharing and filtering a value between components in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a component that pulls in a value `posts` like so:

```
 import { Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
   import template from "./event.component.html";
import style from "./event.component.scss";
@Component({
  selector: "EventComponent",
  template,
  styles: [ style ]
})
export class EventComponent implements OnInit {
  posts = [];
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = {'test': 0,'test': 1};
  }
}
```

This is then looped over in a html template like so AND injected into another component in this case called "mapCompenent" it is also filter in the html using a pipe:

**loop 'EventComponent' content**

```
<input  id="search_events" type="text" name="search_events" [(ngModel)]="search" ngDefaultControl/>
<mapCompenent [(posts)]="posts"></mapCompenent>
<div class="col s6 m6 l4 cards-container" *ngFor="let post of posts | searchPipe:'name':search "></div>
```

**filter**

```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    @Pipe({
      name : 'searchPipe',
      pure: false,
    })
    export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

      public transform(value, key: string, term: string) {
        if(term === '' || typeof term === undefined ){
          return value;
        }
        return value.filter((item) => {
          if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (term) {
              let regExp = new RegExp('\\b' + term, 'gi');
              //this.ref.markForCheck();
              return regExp.test(item[key]);
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

**mapComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, SimpleChange } from "@angular/core";
import template from "./map.component.html";
import style from "./map.component.scss";

@Component({
  selector: 'mapCompenent',
    styles: [ style ],
  template
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  @Input() posts: object = {};

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const posts: SimpleChange = changes.posts;
    console.log('prev value: ', posts.previousValue);
    console.log('got posts: ', posts.currentValue);
  }
}
```

As soon as the page is loaded the **mapcomponent** grabs the ngOnChanges BUT not when the filter is used to filter the posts, the loop updates the posts fine and the filter works there the problem is the mapcomponent. What is the best way to notify the mapcomponent of a change to the posts Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe will not overwrite the original `posts` property in `EventComponent`, so you are only using the filtered version in the `*ngFor`:

```
<input  id="search_events" type="text" name="search_events" [(ngModel)]="search" ngDefaultControl/>
<mapCompenent [(posts)]="posts"></mapCompenent>
<div class="col s6 m6 l4 cards-container" *ngFor="let post of posts | searchPipe:'name':search "></div>
```

One solution is to add the pipe to the `<mapComponent>`'s `posts` attribute as well, but note it can't be two-way binded (`[()]`) then, you should change it to one-way (`[]`).

```
<input  id="search_events" type="text" name="search_events" [(ngModel)]="search" ngDefaultControl/>
<mapCompenent [posts]="posts | searchPipe:'name':search"></mapCompenent>
<div class="col s6 m6 l4 cards-container" *ngFor="let post of posts | searchPipe:'name':search"></div>
```

A better solution would be to inject that pipe into the `EventComponent` constructor, listen for changes on the search input or watching `search` and update another attribute, let's say `filteredPosts` accordingly using the pipe, and use that one both in the `*ngFor` and the `<mapCompenent>`:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class EventComponent implements OnInit {
    posts = [];
    filteredPosts = [];

    constructor(private searchPipe: SearchPipe) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.posts = ...;

        this.form.search.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
            this.filteredPosts = this.searchPipe.transform(this.posts, 'name', value);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the same and tried the pipe in the posts but to no avail I just get: ```Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 9 in [posts | searchPipe:'wpcf-event-cat-location':search =$event]```

Comment: @vimes1984 It's probably because you are using two-way data binding there. It should be one-way. Otherwise use the second solution, which I think it's better than filtering the same thing in the same way twice anyway.

Comment: with the second solution I can't inject the filter into the constructor it's supposed to go into the @Component declaration.

Comment: You need to add it to the `providers` of your module so that the injector can get it.